# Discord.js ban and kick commands not working properly

Tags: discord.js, command, bots

This is the code from the index.js file. This code is inside the client.on('ready') etc. activator.

```
//Ban Command
    command(client, 'ban', (message) => {
        const { member, mentions } = message
        const tag = `<@${member.id}>`

        if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')
        ) {
            const target = mentions.users.first()
            if (target) {
                const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)
                targetMember.ban()
                message.channel.send(`${tag} has been banned.`)
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify which user to ban.`)
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`${tag} You do not have the permission to use this command.`)
        }
    })

    //Kick Command
    command(client, 'kick', (message) => {
        const { member, mentions } = message
        const tag = `<@${member.id}>`

        if (member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') || member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')
        ) {
            const target = mentions.users.first()
            if (target) {
                const targetMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id)
                targetMember.kick()
                message.channel.send(`${tag} has been kicked.`)
            } else {
                message.channel.send(`${tag} Please specify which user to kick.`)
            }
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`${tag} You do not have the permission to use this command.`)
        }
    })
```

When I ran the code the first few times, it worked properly when i just typed .exekick or .exeban but when I typed .exekick and pinged a test user to ban, the message from the bot pinged me in the ${tag} template literal instead of the person that was banned.

I tried to edit that by doing ${targetMember} which didn't work, and when I went back to the current code, the new problem was that it said the `` (`${tag} Please specify which user to kick.`) `` message whether I pinged someone or not. And the code itself does not return any errors.

So I stand with that problem right now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to the problem myself!

It took up 2 parts:

1. I replaced `mentions.users.first()` with `mentions.members.first()` as suggested by MrMythical.
2. Instead of using the `${tag}` template literal in the message that tells you which user has been banned, I used `${targetMember}` which returned the correct member and pinged the right user!

Answer (score 1):

[Message.member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) represents the author of the message. Use the mention instead.

```js
 const { member, mentions } = message;
//mentions.members.first() will be the mentioned member
```

Keep in mind that `mentions.members.first()` doesn’t necessarily return the first mention in the message as said [here](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work)

Comment: I tried using ```members``` to replace ```users``` but that returned the same problems.

I tried another version of the command which now returned undefined instead of returning the user who sent the ban command, which is progress but i dont know how to make it ping the person to be banned. 

Link to new code: https://sourceb.in/p6x7mpxpQU